# What does the number after `exit` command in expect scripts mean

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I am looking at an expect script at it has the following lines:

```
#some heading
send -- "some command\n" 
expect {
-re $more {
send -- " "
    exp_continue
}
">" { }
default { exit 230 }
}
# some heading
send -- "some command\n" 
expect {
-re $more {
send -- " "
    exp_continue
}
">" { }
default { exit 211 }
}
```

So what do the numbers "230" and "211" mean after the `exit` command.

Comment: Why perl tag is here? I just removed the perl tag.

Comment: [what-does-exit-do-in-an-if-block-in-a-shell-script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52649/what-does-exit-do-in-an-if-block-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are exit codes. They range from 0-255 and are used to communicate program success or errors to other applications that might invoke that program (e.g. your shell).

In bash and many other shells, you can check the exit status of the last program using `$?`. An exit status of 0 indicates success, any non-0 status means failure. You should refer to the program's documentation to see what the different exit codes could mean.

See also the Wikipedia entry on [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).

Comment: this also explains the meaning of the Exit Code( http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

Comment: Be careful though, as the exit codes are just a convention, and it isn't enforced by anything. That's why I said to check the program's docs rather than those conventions, many times developers don't follow them or have different interpretations. Codes like 1, 2 and 127 for example you often see in the wild with different meaning compared to those in the link you posted.